# Hide UIAlertView In objective -c

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

I have two method to appear and disappear UIAlertView

```
- (void)showAlert {
    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                      message:@"Do you want to continue?"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"No", @"Yes", nil];
    [myAlert show];
}

// dismiss uialert
- (void)dismiss:(UIAlertView*)alert {
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

The problem that I have, when I want to call my dismiss method, I don't know how to pass myAlert to dismiss method in order to hide the UIAlertView.

```
[self dismiss: // how to pas myAlert];
```

Comment: Do you want to dismiss alertview automatically without selection Yes or no?Please be clear and concise

Comment: UIAlertView is deprecated. Please, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463806/adding-a-simple-uialertview/28383410#28383410) for an up to date example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create **UIAlertView** object globally.

**YourController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIAlertView *myAlertView;
```

**YourController.m**

```
-(void)showAlert
{
myAlertView = nil;
myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"My Alert"
                                                      message:@"Do you want to continue?"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                            otherButtonTitles:@"No", @"Yes", nil];
    [myAlert show];
}

-(void)dismiss
{
        [myAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nirmalsinh.

Answer (score 2):

**UIAlertView is deprecated use UIAlertController**:

use following syntax:

```
     UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController
                                                alertControllerWithTitle:@"SUCCESS"
                                                message:@"Profile picture updated successfuly."
//automatically 2 sec alert will disappear                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                    [self performSelector:@selector(abc:) withObject:alert afterDelay:2];

                    UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                                         actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                         {
                                         }];

                    [alert addAction:ok];
                    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

when u want to dismiss ur **UIAlertController**:

```
-(void)abc:(UIAlertController*)x{
    [x dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@steven you don't need to create any method for dismiss alert. but i think you also check below link because UIAlertview is deprecated you can use UIAlertcontroller instead of it. 
Link:
[UIAlertView first deprecated IOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690086/uialertview-first-deprecated-ios-9)

Comment: Apple is allowed it after OS 9. So now we can use it again.